# What is the precedence when more than one method overload matches?

Tags: c#, oop

I am trying understand OOP concepts in C#.

In the following sample code:

1. why the `ins1` prefers generic method
2. why the `ins2`, `ins3` prefers non-generic method

Note:when I comment out either of the "MyTestMethod" method, still the program continues to run successfully. This snippet is not something from production. This is just my training sample. So, please do not mind the naming conventions and standards.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void MyTestMethod(J input)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Program.MyTestMethod: {input.Val}");
        }
        public static void MyTestMethod<T>(T input) where T : J
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Program.MyTestMethod<T>: {input.Val}");
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            J2 ins1 = new J2(1);
            MyTestMethod(ins1);

            J ins2 = new J(2);
            MyTestMethod(ins2);

            J ins3 = new J2(3);
            MyTestMethod(ins3);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    internal class J
    {
        public int Val { get; set; }
        public J(int i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"concrete base {i}");
            Val = i;
        }
    }
    internal class J2 : J
    {
        public J2(int i) : base(i * -1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"concrete {i}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't have any generic methods at all.

Comment: @Jon now it does. OP used `<pre></pre>`, which hides stuff that can be interpreted as HTML tags, such as `<T>`.

Comment: Indeed. Please take care to post code which compiles to start with in future, checking the preview to make sure it really is the code you want. (And in general, use the markdown formatting rather than HTML...)

Comment: @AntonGogolev: That version isn't going to help, as it was pre-generics. I'd go straight to the real C# specification - not easily hyperlinked by section, but http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029 lets you download the wohle thing.

Comment: This is C# 6.0 @AntonGogolev

Comment: @JonSkeet Whoopsies, my bad. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @Neel the "generic" he means is:  most probably this part here with the line : "public static void MyTestMethod<T>(T input) where T : J" the generic type constraint.

Comment: yes @Thomas// the question has been edited afterwards! anyways deleted the comment!

Comment: Ah sorry @Neel overlooked that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Section 7.5.3.2 of the C# specification is the relevant part here - "Better function member".

The result is more simply demonstrated as:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Foo<T>(T item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Generic");
    }
    
    static void Foo(object x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Non-generic");
    }
    
    static void Main()
    {
        Foo(new object()); // Calls Foo(object)
        Foo("test"); // Calls Foo<T>(T)
    }
}
```

In both calls, both overloads are *applicable* function members. In picking which overload to call, the compiler first checks which conversion from argument type (or expression) to parameter type is "better".

When the type of the argument is `object`, `T` is inferred to be `object` as well, and so for both candidates the conversion is the identity conversion of `object` to `object`. At that point, the tie-breaking rules of 7.5.3.2 get involved, and the first one is:

> If M<sub>P</sub> is a non-generic method and M<sub>Q</sub> is a generic method, then M<sub>P</sub> is better than M<sub>Q</sub>.

So that's why the non-generic overload is picked in that case.

When the argument is of type `string`, `T` is inferred to be `string`, so we have to compare the conversion from `string` to `string` (for the generic method) to the conversion from `string` to `object` (for the non-generic method). Here section 7.5.3.3 of the C# spec comes in, which starts:

> Given an implicit conversion C1 that converts from an expression E to a type T1, and an implicit conversion C2 that converts from an expression E to a type T2, C1 is a better conversion than C2 if at least one of the following holds:
>
> - E has a type S and an identity conversion exists from S to T<sub>1</sub> but not from S to T<sub>2</sub>

In this context, E is the expression "test", S is the type `string`, T<sub>1</sub> is the type `string`, T<sub>2</sub> is the type `object`, and so the conversion from string to string is deemed better - and the generic method is picked.

Answer (score 3):

> why the ins2,3 prefers non-generic method

Because in both cases, the *type of the variable* (not the instantiated type) is `J`, and that is an exact match for your method with signature `MyTestMethod(J input)`. Hence, the overload resolution rules tells it takes that one.

> why the ins1 prefers generic method

Since `T` can be `J2` in the method `MyTestMethod(T input) where T : J`, and it can strongly type `T` to be `J2`, again, it is a better match than the base class `J`, from your other method. So it matches the method with type arguments.

Comment: Yepp that was fast (was a few seconds behind so didn't answer myself). To add to the answer. I think a good read for the question creator would be: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx which is describing how the "where (generic type constraint)" works in c#.

Comment: Thanks for the useful comment @Thomas. There are quite some resources on method precedence that are useful to read indeed.

Comment: The generic type constraint isn't really relevant here - it doesn't come into play in overload resolution. It's only applied to validate the result *after* overload resolution has picked the overload to use. (And in this case it doesn't matter as both methods are fine with all calls.)

Comment: Okay, agree. Exact match always wins. Is there a fault in my answer? @JonSkeet

Comment: Only in terms of calling the overload resolution rules "precedence rules" (which are about how 2 + 3 * 5 binds, for example). I prefer the detail in my answer (quoting the spec), but that's a different matter.

Comment: Neh, we can't all be you... :) @JonSkeet Hope the updates are right.